# bash, sed, awk remove block of text with a duplicate ID and an older date within the block

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would like to remove every block with a non-unique ID except for one that has the newest date.

I hope the examples are speaking for themselves. Any awk and/or sed solution would be appreciated!

Original file:

```
<BLOCK>
ID=1000
Text
Text
DATE=20160101
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
Text
ID=2000
DATE=20140101
Text
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
ID=1000
DATE=20100101
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
ID=3000
Text
Text
DATE=20160101
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
Text
ID=2000
Text
DATE=20151231
</BLOCK>
```

The result should look like this:

```
<BLOCK>
ID=1000
Text
Text
DATE=20160101
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
ID=3000
Text
Text
DATE=20160101
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
Text
ID=2000
Text
DATE=20151231
</BLOCK>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work with any awk on any system:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n" }
{
    id = date = $0
    gsub(/.*\nID=|\n.*/,"",id)
    gsub(/.*\nDATE=|\n.*/,"",date)
}
date > dates[id] {
    dates[id] = date
    recs[id] = $0
}
END {
    for (id in recs) {
        print recs[id]
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
<BLOCK>
ID=1000
Text
Text
DATE=20160101
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
Text
ID=2000
Text
DATE=20151231
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
ID=3000
Text
Text
DATE=20160101
Text
</BLOCK>
```

You don't explain what the output order should be and it's not obvious from your example so I assume you don't care and so the above outputs the records in "random" (actually hash) order.

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu awk you can do this:

```
awk -v RS= '{
   dt  = gensub(/.*\nDATE=([0-9]+).*/, "\\1", "1")
   key = gensub(/.*\n(ID=[0-9]+).*/, "\\1", "1")
   if (dt > c[key]) {
      c[key] = dt
      arr[key]=$0
   }
}
END { 
   for (i in arr)
      print arr[i] ORS
}' file

<BLOCK>
ID=1000
Text
Text
DATE=20160101
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
Text
ID=2000
Text
DATE=20151231
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
ID=3000
Text
Text
DATE=20160101
Text
</BLOCK>
```

Comment: `arr[key]=$0` will take the latest, if duplicates occurred. you can see it in your pasted output.  OP wants the first however. A check is needed.

Comment: I think OP wants the last matched entry. e.g. for key `ID=2000` desired output shows `DATE=20151231` entry but first entry has `DATE=20140101`

Comment: if you check the `ID=1000` case... ^_^

Comment: oh, neither first nor last, he want the **newest date** :-)

Answer (score 0):

this awk cmd does the job for the given input:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="</BLOCK>\n"}
  {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
       if($i~/^ID=/){
              if(a[$i])next;else{a[$i]=1;print}}}}' file
```

it outputs:

```
<BLOCK>
ID=1000
Text
Text
DATE=20160101
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
Text
ID=2000
DATE=20140101
Text
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
ID=3000
Text
Text
DATE=20160101
Text
</BLOCK>
```

Answer (score 0):

using gnu awk 4.0 multiline records and PROCINFO["sorted_in"] - keeps newest record for each ID - preserves relative order of records in input

```
awk '
BEGIN{ ORS=RS="\n</BLOCK>" }
{
  for(i=1; i <=NF; ++i) {
    if($i ~ /^ID=[0-9]+/) id=$i
    else if($i ~ /^DATE=[0-9]{8}/) date=$i
  }
  if(id in recs && date <= maxdate[id]) next
  recs[id]=$0; maxdate[id]=date; order[id]=NR
}
END {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"
  for(id in order) print recs[id]
}
'
```

output

```
<BLOCK>
ID=1000
Text
Text
DATE=20160101
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
ID=3000
Text
Text
DATE=20160101
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
Text
ID=2000
Text
DATE=20151231
</BLOCK>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I like this stuctured solution as it keeps the original order of not deleted text blocks. It seems that I abstracted my example to much, so I cannot make your script work with the XML tags which are actually being used. Could you let me know how it should look like if the ID Tag is formated like this:
`<ID V="1000"/>`
and the date looks like this
`<DATE V="20160101 00:00:00"/>`

Comment: sure - give me a sec - I'll post a new answer with the different sample input

Comment: do you want uniqueness on just the date portion `20160101` or full timestamp `20160101 00:00:00`?

Comment: @Lev -[chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478) waste peoples time answering them and then make the question useless to anyone searching for the answer to a similar question in future as the question doesn't match the answers. If your problem isn't as you posted then accept the best answer for the problem you DID post and post a new question with it's own concise, testable sample input/output, don't start changing requirements especially with comments or you'll end up with a half-assed mush of an "answer" that might produce the output you expect but could be much better.

Comment: @Ed Morton - you are right. Sorry I did not put enough thought to it before I posted the question. That was my first one on stackoverflow, so I have a lot to learn ;-)  Thanks for your advice which I followed and I opened a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235575/bash-awk-sed-remove-xml-blocks-with-duplicate-ids-keep-most-up-to-date-keep

Answer (score 0):

solution for changed input requirements - OP says input ID and DATE lines are like this - check for newer record now uses full timestamp instead of just date

```
<ID V="1000"/>
<DATE V="20160101 00:00:00"/>
```

this awk 4.0 solution also honors relative order of records in input using PROCINFO["sorted_in"]

```
awk -F'\n' '
BEGIN{
  ORS=RS="\n</BLOCK>"
}
{
  id=date=""
  for(i=1; i <=NF; ++i) {
    if(id && date) break
    if($i ~ /<ID V=\"[0-9]+\"\/>/)
      id=$i
    else if($i ~ /<DATE V=\"[0-9]{8} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\"\/>/)
      date=$i
  }
  if(id in recs && date <= newest[id]) next
  recs[id]=$0; newest[id]=date; order[id]=NR
}
END {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"
  for(id in order) print recs[id]
}
'
```

sample input with some different times for same ID and date

```
<BLOCK>
<ID V="1000"/>
Text
Text
<DATE V="20160101 00:00:00"/>
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
Text
<ID V="2000"/>
<DATE V="20140101 00:00:00"/>
Text
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<ID V="1000"/>
<DATE V="20100101 00:00:00"/>
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
<ID V="3000"/>
Text
Text
<DATE V="20160101 00:00:00"/>
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
<ID V="4000"/>
Text
Text
<DATE V="20130101 11:00:00"/>
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
Text
<ID V="2000"/>
Text
<DATE V="20151231 00:00:00"/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
<ID V="4000"/>
Text
Text
<DATE V="20130101 13:00:00"/>
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
<ID V="4000"/>
Text
Text
<DATE V="20130101 07:00:00"/>
Text
</BLOCK>
```

output

```
<BLOCK>
<ID V="1000"/>
Text
Text
<DATE V="20160101 00:00:00"/>
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
<ID V="3000"/>
Text
Text
<DATE V="20160101 00:00:00"/>
Text
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
Text
<ID V="2000"/>
Text
<DATE V="20151231 00:00:00"/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
Text
<ID V="4000"/>
Text
Text
<DATE V="20130101 13:00:00"/>
Text
</BLOCK>
```

Comment: Oh, I see you posted it here. Your output looks good, but I get an error trying to execute the script:
`awk: cmd. line:9:     switch($i) {
awk: cmd. line:9:                ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:10:     case /<ID V=\"[0-9]+\"\/>/: id=$i; break
awk: cmd. line:10:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:10:     case /<ID V=\"[0-9]+\"\/>/: id=$i; break
awk: cmd. line:10:                 ^ backslash not last character on line
`

Comment: the `switch` statement must not be supported in your `awk` - I've replaced it

Comment: the script runs with no errors, but there are some other problems: 
1 - output is scrambled (starts with a closing BLOCK tag) 
2 - output is wrong (blocks with newer times were deleted)
3 - original order is not kept

Comment: what does awk -V say? If it's not at least 4.0 the script won't work properly - it's better if you can upgrade awk but if you cannot I can rewrite it for an older version if I know the limitations

Comment: only `awk --version` works for me and it is GNU Awk 3.1.8 - I opened up a new question as Ed Morton suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235575/bash-awk-sed-remove-xml-blocks-with-duplicate-ids-keep-most-up-to-date-keep