# bash, awk, sed remove XML blocks with duplicate IDs, keep most up-to-date, keep original order

Tags: bash, xslt, awk, sed

I would appreciate any help with this scripting task.

I need to remove every block with a non-unique ID except for one that has the newest date. If the dates are equal, than the last entry within the file should win and be kept undeleted.

The original sorting order of the input has to be preserved.

Input:

```
<DATA>
<TABLES>

<BLOCK>
<ID V="333"/>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20160101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="4444"/>
<DATE V="20140101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<ID V="333"/>
<DATE V="20100101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="4444"/>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20160101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="7777777"/>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20130101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<ID V="333"/>
<DATE V="20120101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="22"/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20151231 00:00:00"/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="7777777"/>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20130101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="22"/>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20130101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

</TABLES>
</DATA>
```

Expected output:

```
<DATA>
<TABLES>

<BLOCK>
<ID V="333"/>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20160101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="4444"/>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20160101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="22"/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20151231 00:00:00"/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="7777777"/>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20130101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

</TABLES>
</DATA>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need an actual XML parser, not some hack with awk and sed.

Comment: "Please write a script that does X for me" is not a suitable StackOverflow question; we're here to build a technical Q&A knowledge base, not to write peoples' scripts for them.  (Also, bash isn't a well-chosen language for this job -- you'd have a much easier time with Python).

Comment: (BTW, selecting items to delete per this criteria is a quite easy thing to do with XPath 2.0; not so much with 1.0, though, which is what libxml-based command-line tools such as xmlstarlet, xsltproc, &c. support).

Comment: Well I was not able to find a documented solution to my problem in the knowledge base. And I am not asking to write a script for me, but just the part of it, which I am struggling with. Bash is what the script is already running on, it has to be adjusted to a new situation. This question is a second try to share my problem after a too generalized try has failed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210025/bash-sed-awk-remove-block-of-text-with-a-duplicate-id-and-an-older-date-within  

The script runs on a server which we do not have root rights for but xsltproc and xmllint are available.

Comment: Just because you're using bash doesn't mean you need to use nothing but bash. It's a glue language, after all -- it's really good at connecting pieces written in other languages. No reason you can't have a single shell function that runs a simple Python script (with its source embedded in the rest of your shell script, even), and pipe through it from your other shell functions. If "I'm using bash, so I can't use any other language" were a valid excuse, then you couldn't use `awk` (an entirely non-bash language) either.

Comment: By the way -- as given here, your input *isn't actually a valid XML document* -- to be a valid document it would need to have all blocks contained in a single root node. Did you take a snippet here and fail to preserve that property as a detail of how the question was asked, or is your input really non-XML?

Comment: Your first output record has ID `333` and date `20160101` but that combination doesn't exist in your input. Please [edit] your question to fix that and clarify what`original sorting order` means as that could mean one of several things and unfortunately your output currently not matching your input makes it very hard to guess which is correct.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I added DATA and TABLES tags to make an an XML

Comment: @EdMorton, the first block of the input was not displayed until I added a header empty line. By original order was meant the order in which the entries are listed in the input, and that works with your solution like a charm even with the added DATA and TABLES tags. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question what output order you want as mentioned in my comment under your question, but this is one interpretation - it will loop through the records in the order they appeared in the input file and print each record only if it were the last one in the file that contained the max date for an id. It will work in any awk on any UNIX system.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n" }
{
    id = date = $0
    gsub(/.*\n<ID V="|".*/,"",id)
    gsub(/.*\n<DATE V="|".*/,"",date)
}

date >= id2maxDate[id] {
    delete maxDateRecNr2rec[id2maxDateRecNr[id]]
    id2maxDateRecNr[id]  = NR
    maxDateRecNr2rec[NR] = $0
    id2maxDate[id]       = date
}

END {
    for (recNr=1; recNr<=NR; recNr++) {
        if ( recNr in maxDateRecNr2rec ) {
            print maxDateRecNr2rec[recNr]
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="4444"/>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20160101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<ID V="333"/>
<DATE V="20120101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="22"/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20151231 00:00:00"/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="7777777"/>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20130101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>
```

You say `date` in your question but I'm assuming by that you really mean whatever is in the `DATE` field of your input so, it doesn't matter for the example you posted since all the times are midnight, but the above uses the date+time, i.e. the entire contents of the `DATE` field. If you want the time of day to be excluded from the calculations then just change:

```
    gsub(/.*\n<DATE V="|".*/,"",date)
```

to

```
    gsub(/.*\n<DATE V="| .*/,"",date)
```

Answer (score 0):

awk solution tested with awk 3.1.8 - outputs newest record for each ID - preserves relative order of records in input

```
awk -F'\n' '
BEGIN{                                          
  ORS=RS="\n</BLOCK>"                           
}
{
  id=date=""                                    
  for(i=1; i <=NF; ++i) {                       
    if(id && date) break
    if($i ~ /<ID V=\"[0-9]+\"\/>/)              
      id=$i
    else if($i ~ /<DATE V=\"[0-9]+ [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\"\/>/)
      date=$i
    }
    if(!id) next
    ids[NR]=id
    if(id in recs && date < newest[id]) next
    recs[id]=$0; newest[id]=date; order[id]=NR
  }
END {
  asort(order)
  for(i=1; i<=length(order); ++i) print recs[ids[order[i]]]
  printf("\n")
}
'
```

output for provided sample input

```
<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="4444"/>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20160101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<ID V="333"/>
<DATE V="20120101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="22"/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20151231 00:00:00"/>
</BLOCK>

<BLOCK>
<TEXT/>
<ID V="7777777"/>
<TEXT/>
<TEXT/>
<DATE V="20130101 00:00:00"/>
<TEXT/>
</BLOCK>
```

Comment: thank you for your solution! It works with a small problem that there is "\ No newline at end of file" I marked the solution of Ed Morton because it works with all awk versions. I appreciate your effort! Have a nice day!